# VBA Excel Adding pictures to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, image

I found a bit of code that helps insert a picture to a worksheet, but the user has to choose which picture is inserted.  I was hoping that it would, instead, choose a specific picture (specifically the company logo) and insert it.  Here's the code:

```
PicLocation = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Work\test_Project\", "CA_Value_AVM, *.jpg", 1)
If PicLocation <> "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PicLocation).Select
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

This code is executed when a button is clicked.  The user clicks it and then the path "C:\Work\test_Project\" is opened and the user has to click the picture.  I need this to change so that the user doesn't click anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as:

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("C:\Work\test_Project\myjpgfile.jpg").Select
```

as that's all the function is returning anyway.

Comment: That was amazingly simple and way better.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I know this was asked 4 years ago, but I wanted to go ahead and update the answer here so that op and future searchers (such as myself) can have a more complete answer.

jonsca's answer is appropriate and will work, but ***your picture will not work if the spreadsheet is moved.*** Essentially, `ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert` *embeds* an image, meaning that if the source image or the spreadsheet are moved, the link will break and the image will not show (not very good for company spreadsheets as OP originally asked about).

However, if you want a picture to work when moved/sent/etc. you can use:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Work\test_Project\myjpgfile.jpg", False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382739/embed-image-to-excel-spreadsheet-vba) for a little more explanation on positioning and stuff.

(Thanks to PaulStock for the original post)