# Embed Image to Excel Spreadsheet - VBA

Tags: image, excel, embed, vba

I need to embed an image to a spreadsheet via Excel VBA, such that whenever I relocate my excel file, the image will still show up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 14):

This code will insert an image on the current sheet and position it at at cell E10:

```
Set oPic = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("d:\temp\mypic.jpg", False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
oPic.ScaleHeight 1, True
oPic.ScaleWidth 1, True

oPic.Top = Range("E10").Top
oPic.Left = Range("E10").Left
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try using the macro recorder?

This is what it produced for me:

```
Sub Macro1()

  ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert ("C:\mypicture.jpg")

End Sub
```

Also tons of info using google search terms: "Insert Picture Using VBA Excel".  The below code is taken from [ExcelTip](http://www.exceltip.com/st/Insert_pictures_using_VBA_in_Microsoft_Excel/486.html) **all credit to the original author Erlandsen Data Consulting**.

With the macro below you can insert pictures at any range in a worksheet and they will remain as long as the picture itself remains in its original location.

The picture can be centered horizontally and/or vertically.

```
Sub TestInsertPicture()
    InsertPicture "C:\FolderName\PictureFileName.gif", _
        Range("D10"), True, True
End Sub

Sub InsertPicture(PictureFileName As String, TargetCell As Range, _
    CenterH As Boolean, CenterV As Boolean)
    ' inserts a picture at the top left position of TargetCell
    ' the picture can be centered horizontally and/or vertically
    Dim p As Object, t As Double, l As Double, w As Double, h As Double
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub
    If Dir(PictureFileName) = "" Then Exit Sub
    ' import picture
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureFileName)
    ' determine positions
    With TargetCell
        t = .Top
        l = .Left
        If CenterH Then
            w = .Offset(0, 1).Left - .Left
            l = l + w / 2 - p.Width / 2
            If l < 1 Then l = 1
        End If
        If CenterV Then
            h = .Offset(1, 0).Top - .Top
            t = t + h / 2 - p.Height / 2
            If t < 1 Then t = 1
        End If
    End With
    ' position picture
    With p
        .Top = t
        .Left = l
    End With
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

With the macro below you can insert pictures and fit them to any range in a worksheet.

```
Sub TestInsertPictureInRange()
    InsertPictureInRange "C:\FolderName\PictureFileName.gif", _
        Range("B5:D10")
End Sub

Sub InsertPictureInRange(PictureFileName As String, TargetCells As Range)
    ' inserts a picture and resizes it to fit the TargetCells range
    Dim p As Object, t As Double, l As Double, w As Double, h As Double
    If TypeName(ActiveSheet) <> "Worksheet" Then Exit Sub
    If Dir(PictureFileName) = "" Then Exit Sub
    ' import picture
    Set p = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureFileName)
    ' determine positions
    With TargetCells
        t = .Top
        l = .Left
        w = .Offset(0, .Columns.Count).Left - .Left
        h = .Offset(.Rows.Count, 0).Top - .Top
    End With
    ' position picture
    With p
        .Top = t
        .Left = l
        .Width = w
        .Height = h
    End With
    Set p = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: We just used this same solution, but it doesnt work once the external image is moved or deleted.

Comment: Then why not ask me instead of down voting!! I would have been happy to help you with further code...

Comment: Oh i downvoted because the OP mentioned that the pictures couldn't be linked so the excel file could be moved so I considered this a bad answer to this particular question.
Sorry, no offence meant ~ i've only been participating on this site activly about a week now. Maybe next time I'll just upvote only.

Comment: The OP requested that when he relocates his **excel file** that the image still shows up.  If he had stated that he wants the image to remain after the image itself has been deleted then you are correct the code will not work,  In he may need to use a shape.  The problem is the OP has not made any comments or marked a solution, so really we don't know.  Perhaps you could read  [when to downvote.](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down) I have edited my post so you can remove the downvote if you choose too.

Comment: if i move the images this doesn't work, which is a specific requirement of the question. This answer is no good.