# How to replace Text with corresponding images

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have an excel document with over 300 records.

In the first row for each record, there is a User Image variable.
This record will always be `username.jpg` or empty.

I have a folder with the corresponding images, all named in the exact same fashion.

Is there any way to replace the text in the first row with their related images automatically?

Comment: Should be as easy as if(condition) column.row.loadimage(). Try doing some research with visual basic on excel. I cant help you much more because I dont speak VB.

Comment: I guess this link is pretty close:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382739/embed-image-to-excel-spreadsheet-vba

Comment: xD Need to finish this in 45min... Im a C# person.. I'm also looking for a method within Excel to do this. I am already generating the excel sheet from XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your User image variable is in column A, then this code will insert the picture into column A and adjust the height of the row to the height of the picture.  You will probably have to tweak the code slightly.

```
Sub insertPic()

Dim pic As String
Dim url As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim he As Integer



url = "C:\User\Pictures\" ' This is the variable to the folder

For r = 1 To 300
pic = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Value ' This is your username file
pic = url & pic



With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(pic) ' Insert picture into active sheet
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & r).Left ' left and top align the left and top of the picture with the specified cell
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & r).Top
    he = .Height ' get height of image


End With
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & r).Select
    Selection.RowHeight = he ' match row height to picture height
Next r


End Sub
```